# how to check for a string pattern in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two types of patterns:

```
'nnn-nn-nnnn'
```

and

```
'nn-nnnnnnn'
```

where n = always a number.

how do I flag the first as 1 and second as 2? having a hard time figuring out how to do the expression. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use `like`, but if you want to check the complete pattern (and you probably should) it's going to be messy:

```
 SELECT CASE 
        WHEN pattern LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 1
        WHEN pattern LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 2
        END As patternType
```

You could, if you are only ever going to have only these two patterns, simply use charindex:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN charindex('-', pattern) = 4 THEN 1
       ELSE 2
       END As patternType
```